# Common middleware vs authentication api

Tags: node.js, rest, api, jwt, microservices

I'm working on a login flow and can't decide what's best for verifying authentication in a microservice architecture.

What happens is that a jwt is sent to the client in an httpOnly cookie where it remains on login.
On every request the cookie is sent to protected REST api's (microservices) for verifying authenticity of the request / jwt.

The two options available:

- I create common middleware for cookie / jwt verification and add it to each microservice
- I embed this service in the auth microservice, and create requests to handle the verification in a centralised way over http(s).

Both options would work, I wonder what are the pros and contras of each approach.
Do you have experience with either one and therefore suggest one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to isolate the authentication service entirely.
The code that calls the api will be common for all the microservices that need to handle all authentication related issues, but the authentication api itself will automatically be changed for all microservices when an update is performed.
I prefer this above pulling changes to each of the microservices individually on updates.
The api can also be versioned if need be for whatever reason.

Http calls form a very small delay, but then again http calls are lightweight.
The same applies just as well for microservices that communicate with each other than authentication.
They will be uploaded to a Kubernetes cluster in the cloud, I assume that these calls will be fast.

The code can still be modified if need be.